# Why is my footer hiding content when I scroll down?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to figure out why my footer is blocking my content. It wasn't doing this earlier so I don't know what the problem is. I tried making the height: 100% or min-height: 100vh but it still didn't work. So I put the entire code so you can see it better hopefully this helps more. If you need more of the HTML let me know but this is all of the code, obviously there's more HTML pages but I focused on just putting the footer.

HTML

```
 <footer>
 <p>Jawed A. Tajzai
    <br>
     <a href="mailto:tajzaijoey@gmail.com" title="email">JTajzai@montgomerycollege.edu</a>
</p>    
</footer> 

    CSS 
    
    body {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #c8d8e4;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    navbar-static:top;
    background-color: #39395F;
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: right;
}

nav a:link {
    display: block;
    width: 6em;
    color: yellow;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

nav a:visited
{
  color: white;
}

a:hover 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

nav a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul a:hover::before {
  width: 50%;
}

/* Nav - End */

/* Index - Start */

#headshot {
    clear: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#aboutme {
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 5px double #39395F;
    padding: 1em 1em;
}

/* Index - End */

/* Footer - Start */

footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #39395F;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }

footer p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

footer a{
    color: white;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: lightblue;
}

/* Footer - End */

/* Project - Start */

#column1proj {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

#projtitle {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

.projectimgs{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.projecttxt {
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

div dd a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

div dd a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

#column2proj {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 3% 5% 2% 0;
}

/* Project - End */

/* Hobbies - Start */

div h1::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#column1hob {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 18%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
}

#column2hob {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 8% 5% 2% 0;
}


#hobtitle {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

.hobimgs {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hobtxt {
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

div dd {
    margin-left: -1%;
}

/* Hobbies - End */

/* Resume - Start */

#bodyres {
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#title {
    margin-top: 8%;
}

#title p {
    text-align: center;
}

#resumeme {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}

hr {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: none;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
 }

div ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
    
.job, .school {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title, .achievements {
    font-style: italic;
}

h3, .title, .achievements {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#main {
    font-size: 18px;
}

/* Resume - End */

/* My Goals - Start */


#column1goals {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px double white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 0 5% 5% 5%;
}

table {
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 30%;
}

#headergoal {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

#goaldets {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

th {
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

td {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}
/* My Goals - Endbody {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #c8d8e4;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    navbar-static:top;
    background-color: #39395F;
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: right;
}

nav a:link {
    display: block;
    width: 6em;
    color: yellow;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

nav a:visited
{
  color: white;
}

a:hover 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

nav a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul a:hover::before {
  width: 50%;
}

/* Nav - End */

/* Index - Start */

#headshot {
    clear: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#aboutme {
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 5px double #39395F;
    padding: 1em 1em;
}

/* Index - End */

/* Footer - Start */

footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #39395F;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }

footer p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

footer a{
    color: white;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: lightblue;
}

/* Footer - End */

/* Project - Start */

#column1proj {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

#projtitle {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

.projectimgs{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.projecttxt {
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

div dd a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

div dd a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

#column2proj {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 3% 5% 2% 0;
}

/* Project - End */

/* Hobbies - Start */

div h1::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#column1hob {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 18%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
}

#column2hob {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 8% 5% 2% 0;
}


#hobtitle {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

.hobimgs {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hobtxt {
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

div dd {
    margin-left: -1%;
}

/* Hobbies - End */

/* Resume - Start */

#bodyres {
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#title {
    margin-top: 8%;
}

#title p {
    text-align: center;
}

#resumeme {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}

hr {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: none;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
 }

div ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
    
.job, .school {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title, .achievements {
    font-style: italic;
}

h3, .title, .achievements {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#main {
    font-size: 18px;
}

/* Resume - End */

/* My Goals - Start */


#column1goals {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px double white;
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin: 0 5% 5% 5%;
}

table {
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 30%;
}

#headergoal {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

#goaldets {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

th {
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
}

td {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}
/* My Goals - End
```

Comment: did you try z-index? I cant see the entire code so I'm just guessing. I'ts either you are missing a closing div or you need to put a z-index on it.

Comment: Hey Crystal. I did try z-index: 1; just now. It does show up a bit more but not all the way.

Comment: add left:0; and right: 0; see if that works or make z-index higher than 1

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work either. It's driving me nuts. It was working earlier Idk what stopped it from working. It feels like my content is just too long if that makes sense.

Comment: you have overflow:hidden; if you change that to overflow:auto and try to add height:auto aswell you'll see your entire content. I wish I can see more of your code so I can help

Comment: hey crystal, I just added the rest of the code hope that helps.

Comment: Try to put this body {margin-bottom:100px; } or more since you have a fixed footer that will help you see more of your content help your body to have some margin hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't work either. I see that when I do position:sticky it sticks to the bottom of the page which is perfect but one of my pages which has less content has the footer a little halfway above the bottom of the page which is the only page which is giving me problems if i choose that solution

Comment: add on body {min-height:1000px} or whatever height; that should solve your issue on your one page. This will just give you an empty space at the bottom. See if that works for you. If you can put some of your html as well so I can see more. The more you provide the more I can help.

Comment: That makes the entire page longer to the point I have to scroll and with the sticky footer it stays in place and I can basically scroll past the footer

Comment: try to put footer position: absolute; then bottom:0; left:0 right:0

Comment: okay so it worked but i made the position: sticky instead and kept the bottom:0 left:0 right:0 man that took a long time appreciate you helping!!

Comment: Oh cool glad I helped you out.

Comment: means more than you know! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
footer {
      position: sticky;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0
      }
```

Comment: yep that works!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to #aboutme
overflow-y: auto;

Answer (score 0):

You need to write like this `footer p a{ color: white;} footer p a:hover{  color: lightblue;}` and also need to check whether the color is overridden or not and check your output using inspect .